# How to format a date column in a DataGrid from VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, dataview

I have a .aspx file with a datagrid in it:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="Gifts"
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
runat="server" AllowSorting="True">
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

The .aspx.vb file associated with it fills it in with a datagrid object.

```
Protected WithEvents Gifts As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid
Public GiftData As DataTable
Gifts.DataSource = New DataView(GiftData)
Gifts.DataBind()
```

That all works fine. However I want to format one of the columns with a particular date format. Is there a way of doing that in the vb code? I know I can do it in the .aspx by specifing AutoGenerateColumns="False" and then explicitly defining the columns, but I want to do it in the code as it's more future proof for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)-Eventhandler:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'If the first column is a date
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = String.Format("{0:D}", Date.Parse(e.Row.Cells(0).Text))
     End If
End Sub
```

If you're really using an old DataGrid, it works nearly the same. Use DataGrid's 
[ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx)-Event instead.

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemDataBound
     If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item orelse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        'If the first column is a date
        e.Item.Cells(0).Text = String.Format("{0:D}", Date.Parse(e.Item.Cells(0).Text))
     End If
End Sub
```