# Displaying date and time in 12h format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, gridview

How can I display date time information in 12h format in a `GridView`?

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: What do you mean, you "used to insert it into 24 time"? You mean in the database?

Comment: @Crono Yes I insert it in the database to 24 time format

Comment: @user3093453 this doesn't make a lot of sense. A date type is a date type, there's no formatting implied as far as storage goes. Unless you are storing it as a string value???

Comment: Store it in the database as a DateTime (12/24 hour format is irrelevant). If possible, use an offset variant to handle time zones. Format it as necessary when displaying it to the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a date column in a DataGrid from VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502918/how-to-format-a-date-column-in-a-datagrid-from-vb)

Comment: This question is *NOT* off-topic, moderators.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hh:mm:ss tt` format , where lower case `h` is for 12 hour formatted hours.

```
Dim formattedTime As String = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

would give you something like : `04:11:21 PM`

For more formats see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)